# What does abbreviation Ber(x) stand for?

Tags: probability, statistics, notation

I am trying to understand the protocol in the following picture for shuffled differential privacy from this paper: [Distributed Differential Privacy via Shuffling](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.01394).

[image]

Here, the authors use an abbreviation **Ber(...)** that I did not came accross yet. From my knowledge it does not mean the bit error rate. I come from a computer science background and did not yet get into too much statistics, so the abbreviation might be clear in general. Does anybody know, what they mean ?

Comment: Is it [Bernoulli](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial)?

Comment: Ah! Yes that could be. Makes sense with the two result types 1 and 0 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of [probability](/questions/tagged/probability) and [statistics](/questions/tagged/statistics), Ber could be short for [Bernoulli](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial).